# Keep format width in scientific notation

Tags: r, formatting, pretty-print

I'm writing a custom `print.xx` function to show a bunch of data pretty tabulated.
The column width is 11 characters, so I do something like this:

```
> format(1234.567,width=11,digits=7)
[1] "   1234.567"
> format(1234.56789,width=11,digits=7)
[1] "   1234.568"
```

So far so good. The problem comes when I have a very large/small number and the scientific notation comes in:

```
> format(1234.56789e10,width=11,digits=7)
[1] "1.234568e+13"
> format(1234.56789e-10,width=11,digits=7)
[1] "1.234568e-07"
```

It should use the scientific notation, ok, but I need it to stick to the 11 character width. I've looked up the `scientific` and `scipen` parameters, but it still goes beyond the 11 character limit. An option could be to check whether scientific notation is generated, and if so reduce the `digits` parameter, but looks cheesy to me.

How can I force it to give me a string with a fixed length, regardless of whether the number is in scientific notation or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you'll have to calculate the digits appropriately.. Something like this, perhaps, will work:

```
n <- 1234.567e2
prettyNum(n, digits=7-(nchar(n)-11), width=11, format="fg")
# [1] "   123456.7"

n <- 1234.567e9
prettyNum(n, digits=7-(nchar(n)-11), width=11, format="fg")
# [1] "1.23457e+12"

n <- 1234.567e100
prettyNum(n, digits=7-(nchar(n)-11), width=11, format="fg")
# [1] "1.2346e+103"
```

Or equivalently with `format`:

```
format(n, digits=7-(nchar(n)-11), width=11)
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case I used:

> sprintf("%11.5e",123456789e10)
>
> [1] "1.23457e+18"

You just need to know how many characters you want and do the right balance between width.decimal, that is %11.5e

Answer (score 0):

```
> sprintf("%0.6g", 1234.56789e-10)
[1] "1.23457e-07"
> sprintf("%0.6g", 1234.56789e10)
[1] "1.23457e+13"
```

Comment: `sprintf("%0.6g", 1234.56789e100)` goes beyond 11: `"1.23457e+103"`

Comment: It's your responsibility to pose a set of test cases that define the range of plausible values. If you see the need to handle 3 digits in the exponents, then just use: `sprintf("%0.5g", 1234.56789e100)`:

Comment: Ok, so 'you need to handle size of exponents yourself'. Cheers